# Know duration of a video with javascript

Tags: javascript, video

I want to change the attributes of a input range depending of the duration of my video and Im not able.

My code:
.......

```
function knowduration() {
        var video = document.getElementById("video");
        var tiempo = video.duration;
        var tiempo2 = tiempo.toFixed();
        return tiempo2;
    }
```

......

```
<video id="video" src="video/video3.mp4" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

......

```
<script>
          document.getElementById("defaultSlider").setAttribute("max", knowduration());
</script>
```

But is not possible.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Video duration is available as metadata. you will have to wait for the metadata to load.

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
console.log("Meta data for video loaded");
alert(vid.duration);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/kozokafejo/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_loadedmetadata.asp

Comment: Hello, Sr. Karthick. With your code how I can make a function which returns me the duration with a var?

Comment: Simple. save vid.duration to a variable like this. var duration = vid.duration or return vid.duration

Comment: var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
vid.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
console.log("Meta data for video loaded");
return vid.duration;
});

?? How I can invoke to get this return?

Many thanks, Im very interested to talk with you in private